# Display always a specific product first on the woocommerce shop grid

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

what I am trying to do here is put a specific product always on the first list in woocommerce shop, so basically it will always be first in product list.

```
(*) ( ) ( )
( ) ( ) ( )
( ) ( ) ( )
```

Something like that, always on the first using woocommerce

I don't know how to do this, please help

Comment: if you are not using the "Featured" option for other things you can use just check it on the desired product and it will pop first

Comment: Hi, i have already tried that but its not going to the top of the list. what i did was the assign a negative value on the product ordering